# Parsing data from an interactive element from a website to Google Sheets

Tags: html, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, youtube

I would like to parse the number of Likes and Comments from this website [Realtime YouTube Live View](https://youtubelikecounter.com/)

I have individual URL links of episodes of a channel for a span of a year.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A_Cc81HOuIyFGoChhyuoC-q2sCdEmqX8N8R_In6dKwU/edit?usp=sharing